# 2SB mixer in radio astronomy?

Tags: radio-astronomy, instruments

In literature about the instrumentation of radio astronomy, I frequently come across a type of mixer described as "2SB".  I'm familiar with single-sideband (SSB) and double-sideband (DSB) mixers, but I have never studied a 2SB mixer.

What is a 2SB mixer and how does it compare to a DSB mixer?  Ideally, I would also like to know of formal references that directly address the topic for further reading.

Comment: the answer to [What would a “crystal mixer” have been in an 1960's radio telescope at 960 MHz?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/16925/8643) remarks that the IF bandpass is quite wide and reasonably speculates that this is related to maintaining a flat phase response for this interferometric radio telescope. Since the IF is centered on the frequency difference, I assume both sidebands are passed.

Comment: I don't know if this is officially a Dual Sideband or a Double Sideband or something else, partly because the accepted answer doesn't actually say anything about what those mean nor what the difference is between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2SB is Dual Sideband, as opposed to DSB - Double Sideband. Here are a couple of papers you might find relevant and interesting:

[a 2SB upgrade replacing a DSB](http://www.nrao.edu/meetings/isstt/papers/2009/2009257260.pdf)

[a paper that mentions the advantages of 2SB over DSB](http://www.das.uchile.cl/lab_mwl/doc.pdf/dsss_rfinger_uchile.pdf)

Answers to [What is the functional difference between DSB and 2SB mixers, and why exactly would 2SB be better for radio astronomy?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/69815/25659) in Signal Processing SE go into further detail.

Comment: Wow, this is a bit of a blast from the past. You are right, I could have answered that better. Six years on I'm feeling a bit of a lack of motivation to address it, but if you have suggestions for edits of the answer I am happy to work with them. Or feel free to add your own answer to improve on this one

Comment: OK, I don't know what the policy is on pointing to answers on other stack exchange subsites

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've made a small edit, I hope this is okay.